# SQL trigger is not getting invoked for [sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData] Table

Tags: sql, triggers, sitecore

For Forms in Sitecore it itself stores the field record in this table ([sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData]) .

I have attached a INSERT trigger to the table ([sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData]) Which will have SELECT query to consolidate records from Sitecore Table for that particular submission and Insert it into the Test table in another Database by using SQL Insert Trigger.

But when I am trying to do so the trigger is failing to insert Field data into the Sitecore table and Test table. Does any one know any solution for this scenario.

Note: When I am trying to manually insert data into the Sitecore Table, the trigger is getting enabled and the field data is saved in both Sitecore and Test Table.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need an SQL trigger? Usually it is recommended to create a custom submit action in the application code to save form data to a different database or send it to an external system https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action.html